# Importing and manipulating a .txt in mathematica

Tags: string, list, import, wolfram-mathematica

I have a huge text file that I import to mathematica. It looks something like this:

```
    In[9]:=import=SplitBy[Import["textfile.txt","List"],"\\t"];

    Out[9]:={{  A   021 2.3 A   002 2.6},{  A   012 2.3 A   001 2.6},{  A   120 2.6 A   111 2.9},{  A   122 2.8 A   121 2.8},{  A   000 1.3 A   121 2.9},{  A   110 2.4 A   111 2.9},{  G   010 2.3 G   001 2.6},{  G   000 2.2 G   001 2.3 G   010 2.4},{  G   010 2.3 G   001 2.6},{  G   110 2.3 G   101 2.6}}
```

EDIT: note that all elements are separated by a `\\t` character.

This is a list of strings such that

```
    In[12]:= Head@import
    Head@import[[1]]
    Head@import[[All, 1]]
    Head@import[[1, 1]]

    Out[12]= List
    Out[13]= List
    Out[14]= List
    Out[15]= String
```

My big problem is in converting this list to a manageable list of elements, such that I can search for those where G is present, not where A is present. I tried replacing the parts of the strings where  was present by a . But then I still cant treat the data as I wanted because I doesn't allow me to search for individual G elements. Ideally, what I wanted to get in the end would be

```
    {{G,010,2.3},{G,001,2.6},{G,000,2.2},{G,001,2.3},{G,010,2.4},{G,010,2.3},{G,001,2.6},{G,110,2.3},{G,101,2.6}}
```

I already know that I will have to use the `Take` command, the `Partition` command to split the sublist in sublists of 3 elements, and so on. But because Im not even able to get the data in a list of lists, I cant make this..

Further, when importing I have to select the `"List"` type. If I imported as `"Table"` everything would be already half done, but the elements "001" would become "1".

Could you guys help me out please? All help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: How hug? While you have a hard time fitting it in memory?

Comment: It has quite a few thousands of lines. The problem is that besides having much text in it, I have to treat several hundreds of these files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Mathematica on this machine, so my syntax may be a bit awry.

Doesn't

```
niceList = Partition[Flatten[import],3]
```

produce a list of lists, where each list at the inner level comprises 3 strings ?  Then, something like

```
Select[niceList,#[[1]]=="G"&]
```

should select the sub-lists which have a `"G"` as the first element.

**EDIT**

If I understand you now, you mean that in your variable `import` you have a list of lists, each of the lower level lists, such as

```
{  A   021 2.3 A   002 2.6}
```

contains a single string ?  In other words

```
FullForm[  A   021 2.3 A   002 2.6]
```

returns

```
"  A   021 2.3 A   002 2.6"
```

I would import the data, replace all the tab characters with spaces and then use `StringSplit[]` (at the right level) to turn each string into a list of strings.  Then `Flatten`, `Partition`, etc. You might find it easiest to start by importing the entire contents of the file into a single string at first

Comment: Indeed, `niceList` works like that. But the main problem is that I still get the `\\t` characters within the strings. Selecting one of the elements in `niceList` gives `{ G 201 3.2 G 009 3.2}...`

I know I can replace each `\\t` in a string by a `,`, but this still does not give me a treatable list of elements that I can use `Select` or `Take`

Comment: Yes, I made it! Now I got a full list exactly as I wanted! thanks! Your tip to treat everything as a string first was essential!

Answer (score 4):

In the future it would be very helpful if you could include a sample of the actual file you are importing.  Nevertheless I believe I can guess the format of the file with sufficient accuracy to recommend this:

```
data = ReadList["textfile.txt", {Word, Number, Number}]
```

If the file is in the format that I hope it should return:

```
{{"A", 21, 2.3}, {"A", 2, 2.6}, {"A", 12, 2.3}, {"A", 1, 2.6}, {"A", 
  120, 2.6}, {"A", 111, 2.9}, {"A", 122, 2.8}, {"A", 121, 2.8}, {"A", 
  0, 1.3}, {"A", 121, 2.9}, {"A", 110, 2.4}, {"A", 111, 2.9}, {"G", 
  10, 2.3}, {"G", 1, 2.6}, {"G", 0, 2.2}, {"G", 1, 2.3}, {"G", 10, 
  2.4}, {"G", 10, 2.3}, {"G", 1, 2.6}, {"G", 110, 2.3}, {"G", 101, 
  2.6}}
```

From there getting records that start with `"G"` can be done with any of these at your preference:

```
Cases[data, {"G", ___}]

Select[data, "G" === #[[1]] &]

Pick[data, First /@ data, "G"]
```

Comment: thank you Mr.Wizard. I will do that the next time - I dont have the file with me right now.

What if I want to neglect a few lines that come before the starting of "G" and so on? As in, I have a few lines where random sentences are written before the start of the lists that are of my interest.

Comment: @SosiKun in that case you would use `stream = OpenRead["file.txt"]` then `Skip[stream, . . .]` (read the documentation for `Skip`) and then finally `ReadList[stream, {Word, Number, Number}]`.  (You should close the stream when done: `Close[stream]`)